# Update record in before_destroy and prevent its destruction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using **Rails 3.2**, Ruby 1.9.3.

I need to prevent a record from being destroyed and update it in the `before_destroy` callback.

Given two classes with the following associations

```
class Course:
  has_many :attendants
  ...

class Attendant:
  belongs_to :course
  before_destroy :dont_really_destroy
  ...
```

I got a `before_destroy` callback in Attendant:

```
def dont_really_destroy
  update_attribute :deleted_at, Time.now 
  false
end
```

The callback does in fact prevent the delete when I call the destroy method. However, the record is not updated. It seemed reasonable since I by returning false I might be aborting any update (I tried with `update_column` as well). However, somehow, it does work as expected when the attendant record is "destroyed" from its association's (Course) form, by setting a `_destroy` form element. The record is correctly updated with `deteled_at` set, and not destroyed.

I've tried debugging to see the if the instances are different when I try to destroy from the course form vs directly destroying the attendant but I cannot see any differences.

When I do it via the course form, the record is updated like this:

```
course.assign_attributes(params[:course], :without_protection => true)
...
course.save
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi instead of using `callbacks` here, why don't you simply update the `destroy` action?

```
 #AttendantsController.rb
 def destroy
   update_attribute :deleted_at, Time.now
   head :ok
 end
```

And you default scope in your model

```
class Attendant:
  belongs_to :course
  default_scope -> { where(deleted_at: nil) }
  ...
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: yes, this is a good workaround indeed. Any idea why would it work when updating through the course association but to with the destroy action though? Even if I find another way to solve the problem it'd be nice to know the reason why the callback behaves like this

Comment: when you add the `_destroy` key to the attributes hash, you will destroy the associated model, but the model will not be destroyed until the parent is saved.
Please have look at this document once, https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I see, although it does not fully solve my question. The parent is saved, and the child is not destroyed (because of the falsy return I guess). Is it because it does so in two phases? It first enters the callback and updates, waits for the parent's save to do the real destroy, and when the save is performed it is not destroyed because the callback returned false? I think this is not a consistent behaviour if it does not work the same as directly destroying a record

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ActAsParanoid Gem which introduces soft deletion for rails.
https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid

Comment: thanks, although adding a whole dependency if there is a workaround seems unnecessary